# Using alternative templating with Middleman

Tags: templates, liquid, middleman, static-site, tilt

I would like to use Liquid templates with Middleman rather than the default ERb.

I know I need to go into config.rb and require it but i'm not sure of the exact syntax I need to use in config.rb to achieve this. I am also unsure of whether I need to just download Liquid from the Liquid website or whether I need to download tilt for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install the liquid gem in your Gemfile e.g. 
`gem 'liquid', '~> 3.0.0', :require => false`.

Then in the config.rb you can set the liquid engine using
`set :liquid, :layout_engine => :liquid`

Then for your files if you add the .liquid extension to the name e.g. index.html.liquid, they will be run through the liquid processor.

Checkout this project as an example https://github.com/Palmaswell/liquid-bourbon-middleman